# ngredux state with big data collection, memory concerns

Tags: angularjs, redux

We are implementing ngRedux for our Angular app. It all works nicely however I have on concern: memory usage, especially for mobile.

Our stores state object looks like this:

```
{
  leads : [],
  filters: [],
  applictionStatuses: [],
}
```

Let's say on of our user selects a datefilter in the list of leads which will grab 30.000 leads from our API (a whole year for example).

As far as I understand redux, the state object will be cloned and then next object will look like

```
{
  leads : [ {object}, {object} ...],
  filters: [ dateRange: { start: {date}, end: {end} }],
  applictionStatuses: [],
}
```

The leads object in the current state will hold 30.000 records.
No when the user changes the date filter, it will update the state and create a new one with the new date filter. It will grab more or less records and at that into leads.

Theoretically the state object could look like:

```
{
   leads : [ {object} ... times 40.000 ],
   filters: [ dateRange: { start: {date}, end: {end} } ],
   applictionStatuses: [],
}
```

Wouldn't this mean that at this time, in memory there would be 3 states stored with a total of 0 + 30.000 + 40.000 leads = 70.000 leads in memory.
Any further change in state would duplicate the state and the leads on and on.

Only until I do a commit and squash the states, I would be occupying a lot of memory for lead records.

Is there a mistake in my reasoning or is this something that is inevitable with redux?

We could decide to take the Leads out of the redux store or put in a separate store so that there are not as many state objects with all those lead objects.

Very much interested in anyones opinion or consolidation.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Redux does not keep previous state trees in memory in production.  See my comment at [Is there any way to "commit" the state in Redux to free memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627553/is-there-any-way-to-commit-the-state-in-redux-to-free-memory/35634004#35634004) for more info, as well as similar related answers at [Can a Redux store lead to a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943762/can-a-redux-store-lead-to-a-memory-leak/40549594#40549594) and [Redux and ALL the application state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489557/redux-and-all-the-application-state/42491766#42491766) .